# Powershell Website credentials help

Tags: iis-7, powershell, web

I'm using powershell to create a web site in IIS.  One of the requirements of the script is that it sets a specific user for connect as.  My question is how do I set this property in powershell. I need to set the password as well , and select 'Specific user' in the Connect As Dialog box.  I also need to set the ip address in my binding statement.

My current script...

```
New-Item IIS:\Sites\www.repair-information.net -bindings @{protocol='http';bindingInformation=':8080:www.ri.net'} -PhysicalPath c:\ri\Web
```

Does anyone know how I can properly set these attributes using powershell.  Thanks for any tips or tricks.  I found this site that has all the attributes for Application Pools, does anyone know if a similiar site exists for web site specific attributes?  [App Pool powershell attribs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347554%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Thanks so much for any help,
 ~ck

Comment: So what was the actual answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2 you should have the IIS Administration Cmdlets available to use. If you need to load the module type `Import-Module WebAdministration` then type `Get-Command WebAdministration\*` to see all the commands. You'll want to check out the cmdlet docs I linked below for specifics.

[Web Server (IIS) Administration Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx)

Comment: Oh and if you're not running one of the mentioned operating systems you can install the IIS PowerShell Snapin [link](http://www.iis.net/download/PowerShell)

Comment: Thanks. I found this helpful.